# Weird horizontal shrinking animation when hiding UIButton with Configuration in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, autolayout

I'm facing this weird animation issues when hiding `UIButton` in a `StackView` using the new iOS 15 `Configuration`. See playground:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    private weak var contentStackView: UIStackView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 150)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let contentStackView = UIStackView()
        contentStackView.spacing = 8
        contentStackView.axis = .vertical
        
        for _ in 1...2 {
            contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(makeConfigurationButton())
        }
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Toggle", for: .normal)
        button.addAction(buttonAction, for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        
        view.addSubview(contentStackView)
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        contentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        self.contentStackView = contentStackView
    }
    
    private var buttonAction: UIAction {
        UIAction { [weak self] _ in
            UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1, delay: 0) {
                guard let toggleElement = self?.contentStackView.arrangedSubviews[0] else { return }
                toggleElement.isHidden.toggle()
                toggleElement.alpha = toggleElement.isHidden ? 0 : 1     
                
                self?.contentStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func makeSystemButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("System Button", for: .normal)
        return button
    }
    
    private func makeConfigurationButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        config.title = "Configuration Button"
        button.configuration = config
        return button
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Which results in this animation:

[image: Button shrinks to the side when hidden]

But I want the animation to look like this, where the button only shrinks vertically:

[image: Expected button hide animation]

Which you can replicate in the playground by just swapping `contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(makeConfigurationButton())` for `contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(makeSystemButton())`.

I guess this has something to do with the stack view `alignment`, setting it to `center` gives me the desired animation, but then the buttons don't fill the stack view width anymore and setting the width through AutoLayout results in the same animation again... Also, having just one system button in the stack view results in the same weird animation, but why does it behave differently for two system buttons? What would be a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you using other features of `UIButton.Configuration` that would not be easy to replicate with a "non-configure" `UIButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, the built-in show/hide animation with `UIStackView` can be quirky (lots of other quirks when you really get into it).

It appears that, when using a button with `UIButton.Configuration`, the button's width changes from the width assigned by the stack view to its **intrinsic** width as the animation occurs.

We can get around that by giving the button an explicit height constraint -- but, what if we want to use the intrinsic height (which may not be known in advance)?

Instead of setting the constraint, set the button's Content Compression Resistance Priority::

```
    button.configuration = config

    // add this line
    button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

    return button
```

And we no longer get the horizontal sizing:

[image]

As you will notice, though, the button doesn't "squeeze" vertically... it gets "pushed up" outside the stack view's bounds.

We can avoid that by setting `.clipsToBounds = true` on the stack view:

[image]

If this effect is satisfactory, we're all set.

However, as we can see, the button is still not getting "squeezed." If **that** is the visual effect we want, we can use a custom "self-stylized" button instead of a Configuration button:

[image]

Of course, there is very little visual difference - and looking closely the button's **text** is not squeezing. If we really, really, really want that to happen, we need to animate a transform instead of using the stack view's default animation.

And... if we are taking advantage of some of the other conveniences with Configurations, using a self-stylized `UIButton` might not be an option.

If you want to play with the differences, here's some sample code:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    
    var btnStacks: [UIStackView] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        let outerStack = UIStackView()
        outerStack.axis = .vertical
        outerStack.spacing = 12
        
        for i in 1...3 {
            let cv = UIView()
            cv.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
            
            let label = UILabel()
            label.backgroundColor = .yellow
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .light)
            
            let st = UIStackView()
            st.axis = .vertical
            st.spacing = 8
            
            if i == 1 {
                label.text = "Original Configuration Buttons"
                for _ in 1...2 {
                    st.addArrangedSubview(makeOrigConfigurationButton())
                }
            }
            if i == 2 {
                label.text = "Resist Compression Configuration Buttons"
                for _ in 1...2 {
                    st.addArrangedSubview(makeConfigurationButton())
                }
            }
            if i == 3 {
                label.text = "Custom Buttons"
                for _ in 1...2 {
                    st.addArrangedSubview(makeCustomButton())
                }
            }

            st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cv.addSubview(st)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                
                label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0),
                
                st.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.topAnchor),
                st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.leadingAnchor),
                st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.trailingAnchor),
                
                cv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
                
            ])
            
            btnStacks.append(st)
            
            outerStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
            outerStack.addArrangedSubview(cv)
            outerStack.setCustomSpacing(2.0, after: label)
            
        }
        
        // a horizontal stack view to hold a label and UISwitch
        let ctbStack = UIStackView()
        ctbStack.axis = .horizontal
        ctbStack.spacing = 8
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Clips to Bounds"
        
        let ctbSwitch = UISwitch()
        ctbSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        ctbStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
        ctbStack.addArrangedSubview(ctbSwitch)
        
        // put the label/switch stack in a view so we can center it
        let ctbView = UIView()
        ctbStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ctbView.addSubview(ctbStack)
        
        // button to toggle isHidden/alpha on the first
        //  button in each stack view
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Toggle", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.addAction(buttonAction, for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        
        outerStack.addArrangedSubview(ctbView)
        outerStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        
        outerStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(outerStack)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            outerStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            outerStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            outerStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            ctbStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ctbView.topAnchor),
            ctbStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ctbView.bottomAnchor),
            ctbStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ctbView.centerXAnchor),

        ])
        
    }
    
    @objc func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        btnStacks.forEach { v in
            v.clipsToBounds = sender.isOn
        }
    }
    
    private var buttonAction: UIAction {
        UIAction { [weak self] _ in
            UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0) {
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.btnStacks.forEach { st in
                    st.arrangedSubviews[0].isHidden.toggle()
                    st.arrangedSubviews[0].alpha = st.arrangedSubviews[0].isHidden ? 0 : 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func makeOrigConfigurationButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        config.title = "Configuration Button"
        button.configuration = config
        return button
    }
    
    private func makeConfigurationButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        config.title = "Configuration Button"
        button.configuration = config

        // add this line
        button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        return button
    }
    
    private func makeCustomButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Custom Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        return button
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

**Edit**

Quick example of another "quirk" when it comes to hiding a stack view's arranged subview (excess code in here, but I stripped down the above example):

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    
    var btnStacks: [UIStackView] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        let outerStack = UIStackView()
        outerStack.axis = .vertical
        outerStack.spacing = 12
        
        let cv = UIView()
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .light)
        
        let st = UIStackView()
        st.axis = .vertical
        st.spacing = 8
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .cyan, .green, .yellow, .orange, .white
        ]
        
        label.text = "Labels"
        for j in 0..<colors.count {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "Label"
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.backgroundColor = colors[j]
            if j == 2 {
                v.text = "Height Constraint = 80.0"
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0).isActive = true
            }
            st.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.addSubview(st)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28.0),
            
            st.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.topAnchor),
            st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.leadingAnchor),
            st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.trailingAnchor),
            
            cv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            
        ])
        
        btnStacks.append(st)
        
        outerStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
        outerStack.addArrangedSubview(cv)
        outerStack.setCustomSpacing(2.0, after: label)
        
        
        // button to toggle isHidden/alpha on the first
        //  button in each stack view
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Toggle", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.addAction(buttonAction, for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        
        outerStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        
        outerStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(outerStack)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            outerStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            outerStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            outerStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    private var buttonAction: UIAction {
        UIAction { [weak self] _ in
            UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0) {
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.btnStacks.forEach { st in
                    st.arrangedSubviews[2].isHidden.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

When this is run and the "Toggle" button is tapped, it will be painfully obvious what's "not-quite-right."

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I just can't get my head around why a vertical constraint affects the horizontal behavior. Would you say this is a bug? You also mentioned other quirks, do you have more examples here?

Comment: @jacksoor - UIKit classes / UI objects / controls / etc do a lot of work "behind the scenes." In the majority of cases, they're great. After working with it for a while though, you'll come across a lot of quirks. In this specific case, it may be a "bug" or it may be by design. See the **Edit** to my answer for another StackView quirk example.

Answer (score 1):

You should add height constraint to buttons and update this constraint while animating. I edit your code just as below.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    private weak var contentStackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 150)
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let contentStackView = UIStackView()
        contentStackView.spacing = 8
        contentStackView.axis = .vertical

        for _ in 1...2 {
            contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(makeConfigurationButton())
        }

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Toggle", for: .normal)
        button.addAction(buttonAction, for: .primaryActionTriggered)

        view.addSubview(contentStackView)
        view.addSubview(button)

        contentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        self.contentStackView = contentStackView
    }

    private var buttonAction: UIAction {
        UIAction { [weak self] _ in
            UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1, delay: 0) {
                guard let toggleElement = self?.contentStackView.arrangedSubviews[0] else { return }
                toggleElement.isHidden.toggle()
                toggleElement.alpha = toggleElement.isHidden ? 0 : 1
                toggleElement.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: toggleElement.isHidden ? 0 : 50)
                self?.contentStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

    private func makeSystemButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("System Button", for: .normal)
        return button
    }

    private func makeConfigurationButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
        config.title = "Configuration Button"
        button.configuration = config
        return button
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: It seems, just setting a height anchor is enough to make `isHidden.toggle()` work with animation. So only your change in `makeConfigurationButton` is required. I need at least a `greateThanOrEqual` constraint so `config.contentInsets` are not ignored. If there's no better answer in a few days, then I'll accept your answer.